# How to "fetch v8" on Android phone?

Tags: terminal

I have installed `Termux` on my phone(Android 7), then I installed `git` then `git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git`, then `export PATH=$PATH:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/depot_tools` But when I try `fetch v8` it says:

```
bash: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/depot_tools/fetch: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `/usr/bin` on Android. Those scripts are obviously intended to run on Linux/Unix systems – but Android uses a different directory structure (e.g. `env` can be found in `/system/bin/env`).

You could try adjusting those scripts – but it seems quite likely this will not be the only thing failing, so be prepared for having to adjust a lot …

Answer (score 0):

This file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/depot_tools/fetch is not available or check for uppercase and undercase sense. File referencing is case sensitive or the for responsible for executing that has an error i mean the files at /usr/bin/env